# Statement lambda must use braces?

Tags: c#

Preparing for C# exam. I'm confused regarding fact that statement lambda must use braces, {}. I lear that from control questions at the bottom.  Lambda below is fine without braces.

```
class A
{
    public static Func<float, float> a = (x) => x * x;

}
```

Question

```
 10 . Which of the following statements about statement lambdas is false?
 a . A statement lambda can include more than one statement.
 b . A statement lambda cannot return a value.
 c . A statement lambda must use braces, { }.
 d . If a statement lambda returns a value, it must use a return statement.
```

Answer:

```
b.
```

Comment: @GolezTrol He must find the *false* answer, not the *true* answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Lambda below is fine without braces

Yes, but then it's an [*expression lambda*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#expression-lambdas) rather than a [*statement lambda*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#statement-lambdas). From those docs:

> A statement lambda resembles an expression lambda except that the statement(s) is enclosed in braces

It's a slightly odd question, in that the use of braces is what *makes* it a statement lambda. Answer **b** is definitely the right one, because it is the only false assertion: statement lambdas *can* return values.

A statement lambda can definitely include more than one statement, and can definitely return a value, although it must use the return statement to do so:

```
// Statement lambda with multiple statements, returning a value.
Func<int> statementLambda = () =>
{
    int x = 2;
    return x * 5;
};
```

One note on terminology: I'd prefer the terms to be "expression-bodied lambda" and "block-bodied lambda", partly as that matches the specification better:

> *anonymous-function-body*:
>       *expression*
>       *block*

However, we're stuck with the terminology we have at this point :(

To answer the point in dee zg's answer (and comments after it), consider these two assignment statements:

```
Action action = () => { Console.WriteLine("Statement lambda"); };
Action action2 = () => Console.WriteLine("Expression lambda");
```

The second lambda expression really *is* an expression lambda. The body of the lambda is an expression rather than a block. The expression is this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Expression lambda")
```

(Note that it doesn't have a semi-colon; the semi-colon belongs to the assignment.)

This is unusual for an expression, in that it doesn't have a result. It's an *invocation-expression*, which is one kind of *statement-expression* to use the specification terminology, and that's only permitted in a few contexts. It's fine in the conversion of a lambda expression though. From section 11.7.1 of the [ECMA C# 5 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) ("Anonymous Function Conversions / General"):

> Specifically, an anonymous function F is compatible with a delegate type D provided:
>
> ...
>
> - If the body of `F` is an expression, and either `D` has a `void` return type or `F` is `async` and `D` has the return type `Task`, then when each parameter of `F` is given the type of the corresponding parameter in `D`, the body of F is a valid expression (w.r.t §12) that would be permitted as a *statement-expression* (§13.7).

A *statement-expression* (as described in section 13.7) can be any of:

- *invocation-expression*
- *object-creation-expression*
- *assignment*
- *post-increment-expression*
- *post-decrement-expression*
- *pre-increment-expression*
- *pre-decrement-expression*
- *await-expression*

In this case, we have an *invocation-expression* (calling the `Console.WriteLine` method); one that has no result.

Note that although the two lambda expressions look pretty much the same here, there's a difference: the statement lambda can't be converted to an expression tree, whereas the expression lambda can:

```
// Invalid: error CS0834: A lambda expression with a statement body
// cannot be converted to an expression tree
Expression<Action> action = () => { Console.WriteLine("Statement lambda"); };
// Valid
Expression<Action> action2 = () => Console.WriteLine("Expression lambda");
```

For further reading about the classification of expressions, there's section 12.2.1:

> An expression is classified as one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Nothing. This occurs when the expression is an invocation of a method with a return type of void. An expression classified as nothing is only valid in the context of a statement-expression (§13.7).

While we usually think of expressions as computing a value, not every expression does.

For more details on invocation expressions, we can turn to section 12.7.6 (emphasis mine):

> The result of evaluating an invocation-expression is classified as follows:
>
> - If the *invocation-expression* invokes a method or delegate that returns void, the result is nothing. An expression that is classified as nothing is permitted only in the context of a statement-expression (§13.7) **or as the body of a lambda-expression (§12.16)**. Otherwise a binding-time error occurs.
> - Otherwise, the result is a value, with an associated type of the return type of the method or delegate. [...]

Comment: Made a correction. He is searching for the false answer, and you showed that the others are true. Probably a typo.

Comment: @xanatos: Yup, not sure what was going on there.

Comment: exactly: only valid in context of 'statement-expression' which is chapter 13. = *statements*. "Expression *statement*" is not expression but, well, statement. What you're talking about is conversion.

Comment: @deezg: No, *statement-expression*, which is an expression. An *expression-statement* is a statement whose body is an expression (not all statements are), and *statement-expression* is one of the valid expressions in that context (not all expressions are). Note that "invocation expression" is in section 12 (12.7.6 to be precise) and that specifically calls out this situation.

Comment: @deezg: I've added a quote from section 12.7.6 (invocation expressions) that expressly calls out that invocation expressions which call void methods are valid as the body of a *lambda-expression*. But they're still invocation *expressions*. If you don't believe `Console.WriteLine(...)` is an expression, which of the grammar productions for *anonymous-function-body* do you believe it's matching? Do you think it shouldn't even compile?

Comment: of course it should compile but, in my opinion, for different reasons than you're saying. Its pretty clear: `An
expression classified as nothing is only valid in the context of a statement-expression (§13.7)`. So, it can appear only within a statement. Which makes outer lambda > statement lambda. And since it is a single statement lambda, you don't need curly braces. PS. i am upvoting your answer as very valuable and you've put a really nice effort into it!

Comment: @deezg: Well it seems pretty clear that it's an expression to me. I suspect that section of 12.2.1 should be changed to explicitly mention lambda-expression bodies as 12.7.6 does. But the body of the lambda really *isn't* a statement, it's an *invocation-expression*. The grammar is pretty clear on this - if it were a statement, it would be an *expression-statement*, so it would end with a `;`. The `;` at the end is part of the assignment statement, not part of the lambda expression. (For example, the lambda could be a method argument instead, with a semi-colon way later).

Comment: @deezg: If you look at the grammar in appendix A, you can get to *invocation-expression* from *expression* (via many other constructs). It's possible that *statement-expression* is a bit of a red herring here.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I've read specs again and i think you're actually right. I must say it is extremely odd to me that expression with no value would make any sense since in my mind that would be expression with pure side effect and it would not make too much sense but that's another topic. Within this context, you're actually right. Thanks for great discussion!

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes, indeed. Especially with someone who cares enough to put such effort into a discussion as you did. Really nice to see and thanks again for it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you've shown is expression lambda and it doesn't need to use braces.

On a contrary, when you have statement(s) lambda, then the body of statement lambda must be enclosed in braces.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#expression-lambdas

Comment: I think "doesn't need to" is *slightly* misleading. It's an expression lambda *because* it doesn't have braces. If it had braces, it would be a statement lambda instead, by definition. (The question is confusing in a similar way, to be fair.)

Comment: well, its not really about braces at all. its an expression lambda because it contains expression. expression being something that evaluates to a value (which in turn gets returned by lambda). whereas statement lambda is just that: lambda that contains statements that does 'something' (that 'something' doesn't need to evaluate to anything...it can be pure side effect). braces are just syntax/notation thing, they are not in a core of lambda type definition. / but i agree better phrasing would be just 'they don't use braces'.

Comment: No, it's *absolutely* about braces, by definition. Consider the body `Console.WriteLine("Hello");` That's valid as the body of a statement lambda within braces, or an expression lambda - even though it doesn't evaluate to a value. Note that `Expression<Action> action = Console.WriteLine("Hello");` is valid, whereas `Expression<Action> action = { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); };` is prohibited by the specification.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton where exactly is expression in that `console.writeline`? and, why expressions exist in the first place? and what is the difference between statement and expression? braces?:)

Comment: It's an invocation expression, but it has no result. I'm not sure what you're asking in terms of why expressions exist in the first place, but the way to tell the difference between a statement *lambda* and an expression *lambda* (which is the issue in this question) is indeed whether it has braces. The difference between expressions and statements *in general* is a much bigger matter.

Comment: is `...{return Console.WriteLine();}` allowed?

Comment: No, but I don't see how that's relevant to the question.

Comment: we'll come to that. you were 'absolute' so i'm questioning that 'absolute' ;). is `SomeDelegate someDelegate = () => {Console.WriteLine("ho ho ho")};` allowed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172345/discussion-between-daisy-shipton-and-dee-zg).

Comment: sorry, cannot chat now...croatia-brasil playing so i am just dropping an eye here from time to time ;)

Comment: I still don't know what point you're trying to make, but having an extended discussion in comments doesn't seem like it's a good idea to me. I think I've made my point reasonably clearly, and there's an answer to your question in the chat when you find time.

Comment: ok, to put it simple. what you've shown is a statement lambda, not expression lambda. but since it has just a single statement, then it can use syntactic sugar form (by removing braces). so, its not expression but statement lambda (in its single statement form). and difference between expression and statement lambdas is not determined by the braces.

Comment: It's good to see we've got concrete disagreement now. Your claim is not true, however. The documentation I linked to in my answer is pretty clear about that, and there's further evidence - if in each case you try to convert to an expression tree (instead of a delegate), the compiler complains about the one with braces: "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree". It *doesn't* complain about the one without braces - because that's not a lambda expression with a statement body; it's a lambda expression with an expression body.

Comment: that brings us to the beginning: can you please point a finger to expression in that case and explain what makes it an expression?

Comment: I'm doing that in my answer now.

Comment: (I've edited my answer with plenty of detail to show why it's valid as an expression lambda now, and what the expression is.)